# Cheap full-featured .NET 3.5 hosting in India?

Tags: windows-server-2008, iis-7, hosting, asp.net

Anyone aware of good full-featured .NET 2.0, 3.x hosting on Windows Server 2008 in India?

Links would be appreciated. Suggestions for either co-located / dedicated hosting welcome.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some:

http://www.web-werks.com/index.shtml

http://www.cyquator.com/html/home.html

http://www.relianceidc.com/

Expect high prices on bandwidth, because from what I remember there is some monopoly over connectivity there.

Unless you need low latency, you should host in the US or even Europe.